# Execute Mutliple release pipeline

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

I have 50+ release pipelines for the production environment and each time doing production has to manually approve each of these pipelines for deployment.

Is there any way to automate and in a single click, all the pipeline gets approved and gets deployed?

Comment: What do you mean approve? Run them or you have to go to some pre-deployment approval?

Answer (score 0):

The only way I am aware of accomplishing this would be to combine the 50+ pipelines into one master release and have those dependent on a separate stage who is deploying to a gated environment.  Assign an approval on that environment.   Thus once that stage in the "approval environment" is approved all subsequent stages will run.

Answer (score 0):

In Azure DevOps, we can configure approvals, It checks all the resources used in that stage, such as source code and follow the target server deployed, this should let managers to check  and agree this deploy, batch approval is meaningless.

If you insist on approving multiple release pipeline stages at the same time. we recommend that you can remove these approvals.

Or we can use API to [list all Approvals](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/list?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1) and get the approval id, then [update status of an approval](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/release/approvals/update?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1).
In addition, if there are multiple approvals in the pipeline, it will only approve the current stage.

Steps:

Create a PAT token->create a build pipeline->click the tab variable and add the variable `pat = {Token}`, then set it to secret variable->add task powershell and enter the following script to approve.

```
$connectionToken="$(pat)"
$base64AuthInfo= [System.Convert]::ToBase64String([System.Text.Encoding]::ASCII.GetBytes(":$($connectionToken)"))
$PipelineUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/release/approvals?api-version=5.1" 
$Pipelines = (Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $PipelineUrl -Method Get -UseDefaultCredential -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)})
$ ApprovalId = $Pipelines.value.id
Write-Host  $ ApprovalId
# List all Approvals and get approval id
ForEach ($Id in $ ApprovalId)
{
    $baseUrl = "https://vsrm.dev.azure.com/{Org name}/{Project name}/_apis/release/approvals/$($Id)?api-version=5.1" 
$body ="{ 
 `"status`": `"approved`"
}"
$response =  Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $baseUrl -ContentType "application/json" -Body $body -Headers @{Authorization=("Basic {0}" -f $base64AuthInfo)} -Method PATCH 
}
```